# Android App Crashes when try to load Info from Scanner

Tags: c#, android

I'm working on an app, that need scan barcode then send it via TCPip port to a C# Server. Single application works, but when i try to read the variable and used to be shown and send it (The variable updates when scan its complete).
Get this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.android.miniclient, PID: 11351
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }}
>   to activity
>   {com.example.android.miniclient/com.example.android.miniclient.MainActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

### The code from Android App, it's the following:

Code to read from reader app:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //get the extras that are returned from the intent
                contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Código Leido:" + contents + " Formato:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //connectSocket("Hello");
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Code for TCPip communication:

```
 public  void connectSocket(String a){

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.223");
            Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 11000);
            a="contents";
            String message = a;

            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
```

---

Code to Update Display whit code readed:

```
public void updateTextView (String finalText) {


        textView4.setText(finalText);

        return;
    }
```

---

I all ready try to Update TextView from other public voids, also try to change the moment when update the variable. But keep the same problem. The reader works separately also the Server/User works independent.

I required to scan result be shown, and used to be call as variable.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle network logic on Main (UI) thread. As you can see you are getting this [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

So you can't run this method on UI thread:
public  void connectSocket(String a){

```
try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.223");
    Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting...");
    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 11000);
    a="contents";
    String message = a;

    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
```

Read more in Android documentation about this: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask

Check:

- [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)
- etc.

There is also a lot of nice libs like:

- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

BR!